# SQL Server stored procedures reading data before insert completed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL Server and stored procedures and could do with a couple of pointers regarding transaction handling on a bug I've inherited.

I have two stored procedures, one inserts a record passed into it, then it calls another one where the first thing it does is read what was inserted.

But sometimes it completes successfully without processing the data. My suspicion is that the selects are happening before the insert has 'hit' the table and retrieve no records, and the stored procedure doesn't handle that.

I don't have time to re-engineer just yet, but the transaction handling looks suspect. Below is a rough outline of what the stored procedures do.

```
procedure sp1 
(@id, @pbody)
as
begin
    begin try
        set nocount on;
        begin
            insert into tbl1 (id, tbody)
            values (@id, @pbody)

            exec sp2 @id        
        end
    end try
    begin catch
        execute sperror
    end catch
end
go

procedure sp2 (@id)
as
begin
    begin try
        set nocount on;
        
        declare @vbody varchar(max)

        select @vbody = tbody       -- I don't believe this step always retrieves the row inserted by sp1
        from tbl1 with (nolock)
        where id = @id

        create table #tmp1 (id, msg)

        insert into #tmp1
            select id, msg
            from openjson........

        while exists(select top 1 * from #tmp1)     -- this looks similar to above, not sure the insert has finished before the read
        begin
            ** do some stuff **
        end
    end try
    begin catch
        execute sperror
    end catch
end
go
```

Comment: *"the transaction handling looks suspect"* What transaction handling? There isn't any in the above.

Comment: _I don't believe this step always retrieves the row inserted by sp1_ Then throw an error. I'll guess that stored procedure sperror also needs investigation. NOLOCK is a terrible habit to develop and suggests some serious code review is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`sp2` is using the `WITH (NOLOCK)` query hint, which can have unintended side-effects. Missing rows is just one of them.

[Using NOLOCK? Here's How You'll Get the Wrong Query Results. - Brent Ozar Unlimited®](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/)

I'd strongly recommend removing that hint unless you *really* understand what it does and have a very good reason for using it.

Comment: I did wonder whether that could have an effect. Would it be an idea to add in a short 'wait' between the insert/reads as well. The issue is extremely intermittent and seems to occur in small batches, so I'm assuming when it happens, the server is busy and the transaction hasn't quite completed the write before the next step wants to read.

Comment: I don't think a wait would accomplish much, other than slowing down your throughput. Unless there's a really good reason for it, removing the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint should be the first thing you try. Depending on your requirements, you might want to investigate using [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker) to decouple the logging and the processing.